# List only private Dataproc custom images

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I have created a custom dataproc image using this command ...

```
$ python generate_custom_image.py --image-name my-ubuntu18-custom --dataproc-version 1.5-ubuntu18 --customization-script my-customization-script.sh --zone us-central-1 --gcs-bucket gs://dataproc-xxxxxx-imgs
```

After creation, I tried to list all the custom dataproc images created by me and was surprised to see 83 images. Mine was showing up alongside 82 other images. I expected to see only mine. How to ensure mine is not in the public list of dataproc images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcloud` will by default list private images in your default project alongside a standard list of "public image projects", as listed under the [gcloud list help page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list); you can make it not list public images, but only your project-level private images with the flag `--no-standard-images`:

```
gcloud compute images list --no-standard-images
```

Another way to see the difference is if you have two GCP projects, and you `gcloud config set project my-other-project` and then try a default `gcloud compute images list` again, you shouldn't expect to see the custom image you created.

Finally, you can also use:

```
gcloud compute images describe my-ubuntu18-custom
```

to see the full resource name of the image along with other metadata, showing that it is nested in your project, and also [gcloud compute images get-iam-policy](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/get-iam-policy):

```
gcloud compute images get-iam-policy my-ubuntu18-custom
```

to assure yourself that the permissions of the custom image are not public.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Tried across 2 projects and figured out the difference.